# Unhandled error in node.js

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

```
app.get('/api/platforms2', function(req, res) {
    var sshcommectionresult = "came";
    c.connect({
        host: '10.254.27.9',
        port: 22,
        //debug: console.log,
        readyTimeout: 99999,
        username: 'bwadmin',
        password: 'bwadmin1'
    });

    c.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('Connection :: connect');
    });
    c.on('ready', function() {
        console.log('Connection :: ready');
        sshcommectionresult = "Connected";

        c.on('error', function(err) {

            console.log('Connection :: error :: ' + err);
            sys.debug("Unable to login");
            sshcommectionresult = err;
        });
        c.on('end', function() {
            console.log('Connection :: end');

        });
        c.on('close', function(had_error) {
            console.log('Connection :: close');
        });
        res.json(sshcommectionresult);
    });
});
```

//If i am having correct username and password it is getting connected.But if i giving wrong username and password.It is showing unhandled error.I am not able to fix this.

Comment: Please format your code properly before posting here, it's difficult to follow. You can run it through [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/).

Comment: how about `c.on('error', function(err) {}` outside `c.on('ready')`

Comment: @MukeshSharma if I am doing that it is going to the error part but res.json(sshconnectionvalue) is not getting updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following approach should work.

```
app.get('/api/platforms2', function(req, res) {
   var sshcommectionresult = "came";
   c.connect({
      //code
   });

   c.on('connect', function() {
     //code
   });

   c.on('ready', function() {
     //code
   });

  c.on('error', function(err){
    return res.json(err);
  });
});
```